# Edit org-mode tags using ido or ivy completion

Tags: org-mode, completion, ido, ivy

I'd like to try a different method of specifying tags than the built-in single character codes.  How can I tag headings using ido or ivy completion?

I think I would like at least two commands:

1. Toggle a single tag on a heading
2. Edit the list of tags for a heading

For what it's worth, I want to use flex matching for this (I don't think that's relevant, so I say that just to give as much intent as I can).

I'm not using org-capture

Comment: FWIW, [`counsel`](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper), which usually comes with `ivy`, provides the command `counsel-org-tag`, which you may like to try out.

Comment: @Basil Why not add that as an answer?  However, I haven't yet found how to select multiple tags that way, without running `counsel-org-tag` multiple times

Comment: Actually now I look again I see I can use `C-M-m` (`ivy-call`) to select multiple tags - that appears to work for all selected tags EXCEPT for the last tag in the list you just selected.  Frustrating!

Comment: I haven't run into any issues with [`ivy` multiple selection](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#key-bindings-for-multiple-selections-and-actions-keep-minibuffer-open); if you can reproduce the problem I suggest opening an issue on the project's [GitHub page](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those users of an [`ivy`/`counsel`](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) persuasion, the command `counsel-org-tag` (added in v0.6 AFAICT) enables `ivy`-backed completion (including [multiple selection](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#key-bindings-for-multiple-selections-and-actions-keep-minibuffer-open) and deselection) of `org-mode` tags:

> `counsel-org-tag` is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in
>   `counsel.el`.
>
> (counsel-org-tag)
>
> Add or remove tags in `org-mode`.

In my configuration I like to remap the default keybindings of `org-set-tags-command` (`C-c C-q`) to `counsel-org-tag` like so:

```el
(global-set-key [remap org-set-tags-command] #'counsel-org-tag)
```

or, equivalently without the remapping:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'org
  (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-q") #'counsel-org-tag))
```

Irrespective of how `counsel-org-tag` is invoked, during completion you can type `C-m` (`ivy-done`) to exit with the currently selected candidate, or `C-M-m` (`ivy-call`) to select the current candidate and remain in the completion session. Typing `C-M-m` (`ivy-call`) over an already selected candidate removes it from the list of selected tags. At any point, you can exit completion with the current list of selected tags by typing `C-M-j` (`ivy-immediate-done`). See the [`ivy` manual](http://oremacs.com/swiper/) for more commands/tricks.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't `ido` or `ivy`, but you can use `helm` for this via [helm-org](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/master/helm-org.el).  If you use "free" selection (`TAB`) after `org-set-tags` (`C-c C-q` or `C-c C-c`), Helm will complete your tags with fuzzy matching.